# Edit 2 - PHP funciton to clean and escape any variable used in Dynamic MySQL - my Code

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-sql

I needed a generic function in `php` that will properly clean and escape any variable used in a Dynamic MySQL Statement. For example MySQL is vulnerable to random user - inserted data. Any sample code , or links are highly appreciated.

Edit 1- I did follow the links posted below. I still feel a concrete example would help.The requirement at work is to have a function which ma look like below:

```
function MySQLClean($string){
    // Contentns
    return string; 
}
```

My questions are

1. What characters should this function escape for mysql . I know a few like `' ^` etc
2. What characters should be removed i.e cleaned ?. This should be generic rather than databsae specific.
3. How do I test it ? - Do , I pass in each string that make up my query to this function before executing the query or do I pass in the entire query  to this function , split them into tokens and then clean/escape each character in the tokenized string and return it by joining it together.

An example of a Before and After "Escaping and Cleaning" the query string will be highly appreciated.

If this explanation seems vague and unspecific - that pretty much sums up my understanding of how to clean and validate the data. I will however be glad to provide any further details.

`Edit 2` - After reading some material on the net and following the link in the given below answers - I have the below following function

```
function MySQLClean($string)
{
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

    $string = stripslashes($string); 

 }

 return addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($string),"%_");
}
```

Is this sufficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) - And that's a highly ranked question, and has a bunch of good answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you've edited your question and I better understand what you're trying to do, let me say this:

**Don't Do It!**

You will run into problems with the character set of the connection, differing collations, etc.  There are a fair number of edge cases that you will likely miss and still be vulnerable with.  For one example of an edge case, check out [Chris Shiflett's Blog Post](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)...

If you're writing a DB abstraction layer and want to create a uniform interface, call the database's escape method in the driver layer.  Don't try to write your own escape mechanism since it will not be nearly as good as the in-built one, and will not be kept up to date as well either...

Answer (score 2):

If you use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html), your data will be cleaned and help prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is that a generic answer? Prepared statement got to be used smartly, not randomly.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Using bound parameters is the smart way, as it's a systematic feature. Escaping for SQL concatenation however is susceptible to omission. (Exhibit: Wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php